# Preventing whitespace to be a delimiter in a for loop bash/shell

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, shell, sed

I have a variable/file (segment_size_date) which contains

```
11-Jul-2017 11:00,604;13-Jul-2017 10:00,604;
```

It is the output from stored procedure(oracle)

I want to delimit the content using ';' so that 11-Jul-2017 11:00,604 is in one variable but it is getting delimited using space.

```
for i in (echo $segment_size_date | sed "s/;/ /g")
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

i am getting the output like

```
(11-Jul-2017) 1st line
(11:00,60413-Jul-2017) 2nd line
(10:00,604) 3rd line
```

i am expecting output like

```
(11-Jul-2017 11:00,604) 1st line
(13-Jul-2017 10:00,604) 2nd line
```

And i want it to be stored in a variable/file. E.g. on the first loop 11-Jul-2017 11:00,604 is stored in a file/variable ( i will process it) and next loop 13-Jul-2017 10:00,604 is stored (overwriting is not a problem )

i have tried using quotes but with no luck.
"11-Jul-2017 11:00,604" "13-Jul-2017 10:00,604"

**One more thing i can't insert anything in the whitespace
like 11-Jul-2017 11:00,604;13-Jul-2017 10:00,604  -- i can't insert anything in the whitespace (11-Jul-2017 11:00), it should be like what it is.**

And the file is only demo , it conatins many lines so **can't use cut -d";" -f1`** , have to use loops.

Shell /bin/bash ---- linux

Comment: use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting... I think you are looking for `tr ';' '\n'`... see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Potential use for `xargs -d` rather than loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just want to preprocess the data so that each datum is on a line.  This makes it easy if you have multiple lines in multiple files.

```
cat *-all-the-input-files | tr \; \\n | while read segment_size_data; do
...
done
```

If your data is in variables (as in your example), this becomes:

```
$ d="11-Jul-2017 11:00,604;13-Jul-2017 10:00,604;"
$ printf "$d" | tr \; \\n | while read var; do echo v=$var; done
v=11-Jul-2017 11:00,604
v=13-Jul-2017 10:00,604
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk:

```
awk -F\; '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { printf "%s\n",$i } }' filename
```

Set ; as the delimiter for awk and then print each field (1 to the number of fields) followed by a carrage return.

Comment: Hi.. thanks 
It is working perfectly fine.
11-Jul-2017 11:00,604
13-Jul-2017 10:00,604
But i want it to stored in a variable/file. E.g. on the first loop 11-Jul-2017 11:00,604 is stored in a file/variable ( i will process it) and next loop 13-Jul-2017 10:00,604 is stored (overwriting is not a problem ).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to temporarily reset the shell's `IFS` variable. That variable is used to control [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting).

```
$ data='11-Jul-2017 11:00,604;13-Jul-2017 10:00,604;'
$ IFS=';' read startdate enddate somethingelse <<<"$data"
$ printf "%s\n" "$startdate" "$enddate" "$somethingelse"
11-Jul-2017 11:00,604
13-Jul-2017 10:00,604

$
```